# Making multiple elements with jquery each() and jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, each, nodes

Well, I have a table with multiple text nodes I'm getting through the .text() function and linking to another table with one row that I'm using as a timeline.
I tried to input in a single td of the text values that corresponds to the correct data, but I only managed to grab the last value I in my loop, instead of getting them all. Here is my code:

```
var tHold, divLine, id, dataTitle, dataDescription;

$(".class1").each(function(){
    tHold = $(this);
    $(".class2").each(function(){
        if ($(this).text() == tHold.attr("value")){

            if($('#1').children("div#" + tHold.attr("name")).length == 0){
                dataTitle = '<div class="r">' + $(this).text() + '</div><br/>';
                dataDescription = '<div class="t">' + $(this).parent().children(".x").text() + ': ' + $(this).parent().children(".y").text() + ' (' + $(this).parent().children(".z").text() + ')' + '</div>';
                divLine = $('<div id="' + tHold.attr("name") + '" class="b"  value="' + tHold.attr("value") + '"></div>');
                divLine.append(dataTitle);
                divLine.append(dataDescription);
                $("#1").append(divLine);
            }
            if($('#2').children("div#id" + tHold.attr("name")).length == 0){
                dataTitle = '<div class="r">' + $(this).text() + '</div><br/>';
                dataDescription = '<div class="t">' + $(this).parent().children(".x").text() + ': ' + $(this).parent().children(".y").text() + ' (' + $(this).parent().children(".z").text() + ')' + '</div>';
                divLine = $('<div id="des' + tHold.attr("name") + '" class="c"  value="' + tHold.attr("value") + '"></div>');
                divLine.append(dataTitle);
                divLine.append(dataDescription);
                $("#2").append(divLine);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

It's been simplified and cut out of a whole context , but all that matters is there. How can I set dataDescription to be multiple divs with diferent values instead of just the last I loop through?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is in the post , no fiddle.

Comment: He means can you create a JSFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: And I've answered that I can't